# Passing current date to select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

So i have got several select options for months, days, years, hours, minutes and i am trying to insure the current time into them with javascript, these forms are being created by django and already have id's but nothing seems to be happening. Anyone know why?

```
{% if form.instance.id %}
      {% trans "Update" %} {{ form.instance }}
  {% else %}
      {% trans "Create event" %}
      <script>
        document.getElementById('id_start_0_day').value = (new Date()).format("dd");
      </script>
  {% endif %}
```

Example of one select

```
<select id="id_start_0_day" name="start_0_day">
```

Comment: check `(new Date()).format("dd")` value is present in the select options, if present then it will selects

Comment: @user3498863 It is not present within the select options :/

Comment: if it is not present you cannot select it, what you can do is, check if present if not add and select

Answer (score 0):

If value is not present in the select you cannot select it, what you can do is, check if value is present if not add and select as below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    var value = 2;
    
    if ($("#select option[value='"+value+"']") == null || $("#select option[value='"+value+"']").length == 0) {
         $("<option/>").attr("value", value).text(value).attr("selected", true).appendTo($("#select"));
    }
                  
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```